# Selenium Java code integrating with Jmeter

Tags: selenium, parameters, jmeter, single-page-application, performance-testing

I have 2 questions:

1. I was able to develop selenium scripts and then export as jar file and then import in Jmeter.

The whole flow worked but that's for only one request/user. if I wanna run concurrently for multiple requests/users it will return me duplicate/failed.

My question is where and how should I create dynamic variable to avoid that problem?

2. is Jmeter right tool to record the UI of single page application for performance testing? it seems like not but please answer with enough details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load tests needs to be [parameterized](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/), i.e. each JMeter Thread (virtual user) should use separate credentials. The most commonly used test element for test parameterization is [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config). You can access JMeter Variables by accessing [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class like:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables;
   import org.junit.Test;

   public class SomeClass {

       public JMeterVariables getJMeterVariables() {
           return JMeterContextService.getClientSideVariables();
       }

       @Test
       public void testSomething() {
           JMeterVariables vars = getJMeterVariables();
           String var1 = vars.get("var1");
           String var2 = vars.get("var2");
       }
   }
   ```

   you will need to add [ApacheJMeter_core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core) to your project [CLASSPATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java))
2. JMeter can record all [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) between the browser and the application under test and this is more or less what other load testing tools are doing. However in the majority of cases you won't be able to successfully replay the recorded test without prior [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)